# Security processing failed with reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or RESTRICTED"). SQLSTATE=08001

Tags: db2

I am running into this error when trying to access Db2 through my code, as well as the cloud console. I am using Db2 hosted on IBM Cloud.

```
Security processing failed with reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or RESTRICTED").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

I am unable to perform SQL queries, or access any of my table data through the console, or perform any admin access. I cannot figure out what the issue is let alone how to solve it. What could be my issue?

Comment: As the error message says, your user ID is probably locked (after a number of failed connection attempts, may be). Contact IBM Cloud support. There's nothing anyone else can do to help you.

Comment: thats unfortunate, but thank you for the response. will do so.